# after_relationship_add logic hook update query doesn't work in sugarcrm

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created a after_relationship_add logic hook in cases module and in this module there is a custom field for one of the custom module relationship data to be inserted. The hook is called properly, and everything is working fine. but when I am updating the case record in hook logic, the update query is not working. But if I add a die(); statement after update query execution, the record gets updated. logic hook code is given below

```
public function updateData($bean, $event, $arguments){  

    $caseid = $bean->id;
    $dataid = $arguments['related_id'];
    $query = "SELECT name FROM data1_data where id = '" .$dataid. "'";
    $dataresult = $GLOBALS['db']->query($query , false);
    $dataname = "";
    while (($row = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($dataresult )) != null) {
       $dataname = $row['name'];               
    }

    $newQuery = 'UPDATE cases_cstm SET data_c = "'.$dataname.'" where id_c = "'.$caseid.'" ';
    $newResult = $GLOBALS['db']->query($newQuery);   

    /* here when die() statement is added update query executes properly and 
     * after removing die(); statement nothing happens.*/
    die();
}
```

Can any one help me in this issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SugarCRM, you should practically never interact with the database directly. Almost anything you'll need to do can be done with the SugarBean object and it's extensions. What you're seeing here is a great example of why: your update is hitting the database, but the rest of the SugarCRM update that loads immediately afterwards is wiping it out.

I've rewritten your function using SugarBean and BeanFactory. Notice how much less code is needed, and I expect you'll find that it works because it won't cause additional updates.

The one bit I'm not sure about is whether or not you really need the `$bean->save();` at the end. If we were in a before_save logic hook it wouldn't be needed, but I use the after_relationship_add less frequently, so it might be necessary here.

```
/**
 * @param $bean aCase object
 * @param $event string, or specifically 'after_relationship_add'
 * @param $arguments array
 */
public function updateData($bean, $event, $arguments){  
    /*
     * Instead of loading the data1_data information from the database
     * directly, consider using the SugarBean PHP object, as this is a SugarCRM
     * best practice. 
     * 
     * Note that we return early if the data1_data object cannot be found or
     * if the 'name' value is blank (as that would make the rest of this script
     * useless)
     */
    $data = BeanFactory::getBean('data1_data',$arguments['related_id']);
    if(empty($data->name)) return;
    $dataname = $data->name;

    /*
     * Instead of sending an update query directly to the database, use the 
     * SugarBean objects, one's loaded already in $bean. Saving objects 
     * with the SugarBean objects instead of direct SQL will ensure that 
     * all workflows and logic hooks are executed correctly. Further, 
     * updating with direct SQL *before* a pending update is sent (such as
     * in a logic hook) will likely overwrite whatever update we're making
     * in SQL. 
     */
    $bean->data_c = $dataname;
    $bean->save();

}
```